# How to specify the plot region for plot

Tags: plotting, regions

I have five curves `{k^2 + 2, k^2 + 3, -k^2 + 2, -k^2 + 1, Sqrt[k^2]}`, as seen below; how can I get rid of the blue and red ones inside the white region? Is there an option, like in `DensityPlot`, to specify plot region here to be above the black dashed curve?

Here's the code I used:

```
Plot[{k^2 + 2, k^2 + 3, -k^2 + 2, -k^2 + 1, Sqrt[  (k^2)], 
  6, -6}, {k, -2, 2}, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 PlotRange -> {0, 4}, 
 Filling -> {2 -> {{6}, {Yellow}}, 2 -> {{1}, {LightRed}}, 
   1 -> {{3}, {LightBlue}}, 3 -> {{4}, {Green}}, 4 -> {{5}, {Orange}},
    5 -> {{7}, {White}}}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red, Red, Blue, {Black, Dashed}}, 
 AxesOrigin -> {-2, 0}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `RegionFunction`:

```
Plot[{k^2 + 2, k^2 + 3, -k^2 + 2, -k^2 + 1, Sqrt[k^2], 4.1}, {k, -2, 
  2}, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> {0, 4}, 
 Filling -> {4 -> {{5}, Orange}, 4 -> {{3}, Green}, 3 -> {{5}, Green},
    3 -> {{1}, LightBlue}, 5 -> {{1}, LightBlue}, 
   1 -> {{2}, LightRed}, 2 -> {{6}, Yellow}}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red, Red, Blue, {Black, Dashed}}, Axes -> False, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Sqrt[x^2] <= y]]
```

[image]

I also cleaned the `Filling`.