# How to Fill Between two Curves

Tags: plotting, filling

I want to fill between the curves on the domain {0,1}. I only want it on that domain, does anyone know how to do that with the given curves? Sorry for a probably simple question, I'm a beginner to *Mathematica*.

```
f[x_]=x^2;
g[x_] = x;

Plot[{f[x], g[x]}, {x, 0, 1.25}, PlotLabels -> {"f", "g"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Try `Filling->{1->{{2}, {Yellow, White}}}`. See [Filling](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Filling.html)

Comment: Related: [(128311)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128309/how-to-specify-the-plot-region-for-plot/128311#128311).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
f[x_] = x^2;
g[x_] = x;
```

For 2D graphics you can use the syntax `Filling -> {ij -> {{ik}, {gk-, gk+}}}` to fill from object `ij` to `ik` using graphics directive `gk-` when `ij` is above `ik` and graphics directive `gk-` when `ik` is below `ij`.

```
Plot[
 {f[x], g[x]},
 {x, 0, 1.25},
 PlotLabels -> {"f", "g"},
 Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, {Yellow, None}}}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 9):

A careful reading of the [`Filling`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Filling.html) option for [`Plot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html) will let you fill selectively:

```
f[x_] := x^2;
g[x_] := x;

Plot[{f[x], g[x]}, {x, 0, 1.25}, PlotLabels -> {"f", "g"},
  Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, {Directive[Green, Opacity[.3]], None}}}]
```

Also, be aware of the difference between [`Set`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) (`=`) and [`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html) (`:=`) when defining functions.

> [image]

Answer (score 6):

I would look [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40146/filling-only-part-of-a-plot).

Modifying the form slightly:

```
f[x_] := x^2;
g[x_] := x;
plotfun[{r1_, r2_}, opts___] := Plot[{f[x], g[x]}, {x, r1, r2}, opts]

Show[plotfun[{0, 1.25}, PlotLabels -> {"f", "g"}],plotfun[{0, 1}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}]]
```

Yields:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The filling option works only correct if there is a change in sign regarding the difference of the two functions. If the functions are only touching each other then one needs to use two plotting commands, one without filling for the graphs and and another one for the filling itself.
E.g. f[x_] := 2 x; g[x_] := x^2/a + a; a = 1/2;